# Sharepoint List Inserted Into Non-Sharepoint Site

Tags: list, sharepoint

Is it possible to integrate a hosted Sharepoint Site List, into a primarily HTML/CSS website?  Our Sharepoint site currently has lists for internal use, that could also be used for our public facing website (small non-profit). Thus negating work that currently has to be done twice.  PDF lists that include policies, minutes, nothing confidential.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can use the WebServices of Sharepoint. However if your public site is not on the same domain than your Sharepoint, you could have some challenging issues: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.